# Missing 'Move to Trash' option from bulk select box

Tags: wp-admin, bulk, trash

I seem to be missing the bulk select option for moving multiple items to the trash. This happens when all plugins are deactivated as well. Has anyone come across this before?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vRkB.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine that your role does not have the capability to delete posts. Maybe try installing a [Members](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/) plugin and take a look.

Comment: This was it. My 'Administrator' role was missing a number of capabilities. I actually wound up using https://wordpress.org/plugins/capability-manager-enhanced/ to fix it.